# how to add comments and annotations in PDF viewer in angular

Tags: angular, pdf, annotations, pdf-viewer, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I am a beginner of Angular. I am working on a sample application wherein I want to load a PDF file, view, edit and save it. In addition, I also want to perform annotations like write comments, adding shapes, images, etc.

I had come across this PDFTron Webviewer (https://www.pdftron.com/samples/web/samples/viewing/viewing/
) which has all the features I am looking for, but it’s a licensed one.

I have tried “pdf-viewer”, “ng2-pdfjs-viewer”, but these have only basic features like open file, download, print and traverse through pages, zoom-on, zoom-out.

Please help me in how to add comments and do annotations in the PDF file from Angular application. or please suggest any alternate solutions

Comment: Check this https://annotationeer.netlify.app/ . It runs on top of the PDF.JS Viewer and is independent so any new version of PDF.js should have no issues.

Answer (score 6):

FYI: I am the auther of ng2-pdfjs-viewer.

All pdf viewers built on top of Mozilla's PDFJS only have viewing capabilities, which are free to use on most occasions based on the license.

PDF Editors is what you are looking for. ng2-pdfjs-viewer or similar packages does not provide this functionality. They are intended for "Viewing" and not editing.

In my experience good pdf editing services and softwares always comes at a cost(Like adobe reader is free, but not the writer). You may try to find a free to use open source one.

Though I haven't used it, the below link points to an editor with several stars(might represent quality)
https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/highkite/pdfAnnotate

This is a pure javascript library that supports writing annotations to a PDF file on the client side too.
Depending on the file size or number of annotation added, writing on the browser can be slow.

It does not support editing PDF files though.