# pdfAnnotate/other pdf annotation library for annotating PDF in Angular

Tags: angular, pdf.js, pdf-annotations, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

Similar to the OP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202101/how-to-add-comments-and-annotations-in-pdf-viewer-in-angular). I'm working an Angular application that loads PDF, and allows programmatically (required) and manually (optional) adding annotations. This may be somehow duplicate to the linked post, but to clarify, in my case only adding annotation is needed, not actually editing/manipulating the original PDF file in other ways.

I found this [pdfAnnotate](https://github.com/highkite/pdfAnnotate) library that seems promising. However, getting pdf.js to work in Angular (I'm in Angular 17) is challenging - no success yet. I did try both [ng2-pdfjs-viewer](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer) and [ngx-extended-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer) in my project. They both work well as for viewing, but -

- ngx-extended-pdf-viewer seems to only offer Ink (freehand) annotation and text annotation at this time, While I'm looking for more types like square, circle, Popup, etc. Please correct me if I'm overlooking something.
- ng2-pdf-viewer doesn't offer annotation feature currently

My questions -

1. Anyone has or can offer a working example of Angular(preferably 17) project with pdf.js integrated? If I can get that work it's one step towards using the pdfAnnotation library...
2. Or, can I use [pdfAnnotation](https://github.com/highkite/pdfAnnotate) library directly with ng2-pdf-viewer? Hoping the author @int-i would advise :) BTW ng2-pdf-viewer is such a nice component - thanks for creating it.
3. Any recommendation is welcome. I also researched some of the commercial pdf view/annotation libraries out there. They are nice but too costly for our use case, plus having more features that we don't need at this time.

Thanks!

Comment: in ng2-pdfjs-viewer [website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer)'s "what is new?" section, "Direct access to underlying viewer" is mentioned. Does this mean it's possible/more straightforward than before to integrate pdfAnnotate with ng2-pdfjs-viewer?